# Please stop sending notification mails for job listings without the subscribed tag

Tags: support, email, stack-overflow-jobs

I know that tags in a job listing are not 100% accurate - some employers simply add unnecessary tags.

but let's be positive and leave those aside, there are those who use it properly - They tag the core technologies that they are looking for, and somewhere in the description they mention it's good to have little experiece in `x`, `y` etc as well. This is good.

What is not good is that I'm getting emails regarding jobs that are not relevant to me.

For example, I've subscribed for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) jobs, and I'm getting emails regarding job postings for C++ developers, c# developers etc.

I wouldn't complain if the jop poster has incorrectly tagged JavaScript in those posting, but they haven't. They merely mention something along the lines of *"it's good to have some experience in scripting languages such as JavaScript..."* they didn't even bother to tag it in their post because that is not the core skill they are looking for and they have clearly conveyed the message by **not tagging JavaScript**.

These are few examples I got notified today:

- [Senior Software Engineer - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/108778/senior-software-engineer-c-plus-plus-autodesk)
- [Full Stack Ruby on Rails Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/113446/full-stack-ruby-on-rails-developer-nanameue-inc)
- [Senior PHP Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/92745/senior-php-developer-coolblue)
- [Technical Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/108670/technical-architect-compsych-corporation) (tagged Java, Spring, Hibernate, .net)

That covers most of the mainstream languages which are clearly not tagged JavaScript.

These are just examples I got today, But I have been observing this for some time now. The notification mail is almost useless.

Why am I getting notifications for those? Please update the algorithm to only send posts that is **tagged** with the technology I subscribed for.

Comment: I can't see any alerts associated with your SO account. Is the alert addressed to the same email address you use for SO?

Comment: @DeanWard It's the same email, here's a [screenshot of todays email](http://imgur.com/hQeOfBL)

Comment: Protip: Look at the production database when checking things for meta posts. Doh :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an [advanced search query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs) in your alert configuration in order to only match jobs that have the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

When editing your job alert, the keywords field should contain

```
javascript
```

Try replacing it with

```
[javascript]
```

Comment: I haven't used the job alerts, but this kind of behaviour would be surprising to me too.. I understand it makes sense in terms of keeping it the same as the rest of the site.. but in this case it might make sense to default to tag search unless explicitly asking for text search, ie `"javascript"`

Comment: This definitely reduces the number of search results... will wait a little to confirm what happens to the notifications

Comment: Well looks like this worked, all the jobs I got today had javascript tag in those